# Remote Desktop Connection to server on Internet fails from home router but works with 4G

Tags: networking, windows-10, remote-desktop

I'm on Windows Pro 10 with latest update. I'm trying to use Remote Desktop Connection to connect to a server (on public IP on Internet). This used to be ok until I came back from holiday where I discovered that I'm not able to login anymore using RDC when I am connected to my home network. It says "This computer can't connect to remote computer", but as soon I connect with 4G (instead of home router), it connects with no issues. I called ISP but they said there is no issue and didn't block any address related to this server IP. I tried flushing DNS and restarted the router. I tried changing my connection DNS to : 8.8.8.8 but no effect.

Note : I can ping and get success replies .

The router caching/dns could be the main cause but I don't know what else to do with it.

Comment: Do you connect using a hostname or an IP? E.g. in your RDP software do you enter `remotepc.example.com` or `1.2.3.4`?

Comment: I used IP . This is how I always used to login .

Comment: Ask the people who host the server if your public IP is blocked. There are systems that can ban an IP address upon logging in too many times with the wrong password. RDP Guard and RDP Defender are 2 names of programs that will do this. They will add a firewall rule to block your ip on the RDP port, so ping will work, but RDP won't.

Comment: I asked the hosting company about this but they checked and confirmed none of these is happening . They even disabled firewall while checking and the issue is still there.